# Why does dconf differ from dconf-editor?

Tags: kali-linux, xdg, dconf

[Kali 2016.2](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) in Qemu:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64  -boot d -m 5000 --enable-kvm 
-cdrom kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso
```

I'm trying to list `root` dir:

```
# /usr/bin/dconf list /
org/
```

But `dconf-editor` shows me five dirs: `apps`, `ca`, `desktop`, `org` and `system`.

Moreover, full dump:

```
# /usr/bin/dconf dump /
```

does not match GUI version...

Taking look at compilations:

```
# ldd `which dconf` | awk '{print $1}' | while read i;do echo; echo $i;ldd /usr/bin/dconf-editor | grep $i;done
```

Everything matches. Both of applications compiled against the same set of libraries. Moreover, `dconf-editor` must be just a GUI, it must use `dconf` as a call inside.

Why it is different? Is it retard of development? As I can read from `License` field, it was Canonical couple of years ago, but now it is one man. Canonical sucked every juices from project and lived it alone...

And how can I list from console/terminal this fields of `dconf-editor`(GUI) which are not visible in `dconf`??

Comment: The dconf database is session-specific - it looks like you are running the terminal `dconf` command as root, who (I hope) doesn't have a running desktop session

Comment: It is  Kali 2016.2, pentest-oriented distributive, there is pretty everything as root...

Comment: `# ps -C gnome-session-binary -o user= ->>>
root`, X - too as root.

Comment: Is `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` set in the root terminal where you ran `dconf`?

Comment: `# echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS  ->>>
unix:path=/run/user/0/bus`

Answer (score 1):

The `dconf` command gives you access to the `dconf key-value` database. This database is empty by default; so, you only see via `dconf` the settings that have already been edited, and you can only read the name of the key, and its value.

`Dconf Editor` do not only call this database. It also calls the “GSchema” API, that is part of the `GLib` (the base library of Gtk and various other libraries).

A schema is a file describing keys –it’s what provides a summary, a description, etc. of the keys– and is defined by the applications, and mapped to a path in the `dconf` database, that is used as back end.

If you want to have access to schemas in terminal, then you should use the command `gsettings`. This command will let you read its documentation, but it’s harder to imagine that as a tree of settings, that’s in what `Dconf` Editor is quite convenient.

Yes, Dconf Editor should be renamed, for clarity purposes. I prefer `gsettings` over `dconf` because of its ability of doing multiple operations not related t database.

Comment: Would you please include reference to your answer?